# alternative for github : <repo-name> in gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to build the [docrails](https://github.com/lifo/docrails) in my system. When I clone the repo and do `bundle install` as the guides say.

I get the following error

`You passed :github as an option for gem 'rails/active_record_deprecated_finders'
, but it is invalid.`

Entry in gemfile looks like this:
`gem 'rails/active_record_deprecated_finders', github: 'rails/active_record_deprecated_finders'`

To avoid that what I am doing is commenting the rest of the line like this:
`gem 'rails/active_record_deprecated_finders'#, github: 'rails/active_record_deprecated_finders'`

Then it foregoes that and the next problem arrives with the error message saying:
`Could not find gem 'active_record_deprecated_finders (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in any
of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.`

**Environment specs**:

Bundler version 1.0.21

Rails 3.2.3

Win7 64bit

**Question**

1. I dont know why its looking for x86 when my System is 64bit.Is there any work around for this? or its a bug?
2. If gem file couldn't accept `github:` as parameter why is it there in the first place?

Please let me know if there are any workarounds to this problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `:github` option is just shorthand for a longer :git option:

```
gem :foo, :github => 'rails/foo'
```

Is just short for

```
gem :foo, :git => 'git://github.com/rails/foo.git'
```

This is new in bundler 1.1 which is why it doesn't work on your setup. You could rewrite the gemfile but it would probably be easier to update bundler. In addition bundler 1.1 is a lot faster than 1.0

Comment: Thanks a lot Frederick, I upgraded bundler & that does solve vital part of my question. _My another question is why does it look for x86 version of that gem when my system is a 64bit._

Comment: Did you install a 32bit version of ruby?

Comment: I installed it using [Ruby Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), it doesn't have bit versions on their site & yeah I think its 32-bit as its in my `Program files(x86)` folder.